# nVidia Thrust: device_ptr Const-Correctness

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

In my project which makes extensive use of nVidia CUDA, I sometimes use Thrust for things that it does very, very well. *Reduce* is one algorithm that is particularly well implemented in that library and one use of *reduce* is to normalise a vector of non-negative elements by dividing each element by the sum of all elements.

```
template <typename T>
void normalise(T const* const d_input, const unsigned int size, T* d_output)
{
    const thrust::device_ptr<T> X = thrust::device_pointer_cast(const_cast<T*>(d_input));
    T sum = thrust::reduce(X, X + size);

    thrust::constant_iterator<T> denominator(sum);
    thrust::device_ptr<T> Y = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_output);
    thrust::transform(X, X + size, denominator, Y, thrust::divides<T>());
}
```

(`T` is typically `float` or `double`)

In general, I don't want to depend on Thrust throughout my entire code base so I try to make sure that functions like the above example accept only raw CUDA device pointers. This means that once they are compiled by NVCC, I can link them statically into other code without NVCC.

This code worries me, however. I want the function to be const-correct but I can't seem to find a `const` version of `thrust::device_pointer_cast(...)` - Does such a thing exist? In this version of the code, I have resorted to a `const_cast` so that I use `const` in the function signature and that makes me sad.

On a side note, it feels odd to copy the result of *reduce* to the host only to send it back to the device for the next step. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it's [non const](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__memory__management__functions.html#gac4f463a34cc4b411206ef0a6a4e7ef83)? Why do you cast?

Comment: I cast because it won't compile without the cast. "no instance of constructor "thrust::pointer<Element, Tag, Reference, Derived>::pointer [with Element=float, Tag=thrust::device_system_tag, Reference=thrust::device_reference<float>, Derived=thrust::device_ptr<float>]" matches the argument list" (What you've linked, there, is the copy-constructor.)

Comment: @Xharlie Have you tried using with the const-correct device ptr? That is, `thrust::device_ptr<const T>`?

Comment: @Angew - That works. `thrust::device_ptr<const T> X = thrust::device_pointer_cast<const T>(d_input)` is just fine.

Comment: @Angew - Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want const-correctness, you need to be const-correct everywhere. `input` is a pointer to `const T`, therefore so should be `X`:

```
const thrust::device_ptr<const T> X = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_input);
```

Comment: @Drop Yes (though that would be `const auto X = ...` to match the OP's code exactly).

Comment: I'd have learned little from this question if @Angew had used `auto` in his answer. The very fact that he gave me the full type specification is what makes it helpful.

Comment: Make sure T matches the type contained in the pointer as well. For example, you'll get that error if d_input is uint64 and you try:

const thrust::device_ptr<float> X = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_input);