# passing a const reference of a tuple to a functor

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, thrust

I have a `functor` which needs to modify tuple values. So i am passing a `const reference` to it.

Here is my code :

```
void operator() (thrust::tuple<const int&,const float&> tup)
{
    thrust::get<1> (tup) += 10;
    thrust::get<0> (tup) += 10;

}
```

But I am getting an error : 
`error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue`

Clearly I am not modifying the reference, I am only modifying the value referenced by the tuple.

Comment: There are no "const references" in C++ (references are never reseatable). The `const` always refers to the bound value.

Comment: Don't know thrust library, but in most libraries, tuples are immutable for a good reason. Might that also be the case in this library?

Comment: When I am not passing a const reference the i get this  error: a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "const thrust::device_reference<int>"

Comment: `thrust::get<1> (tup)` is not a "modifiable lvalue" exactly because you wrote `const` (and the same for the other part of it). Since `thrust::device_reference` already "acts like" a reference, you should be able to just pass them by value and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..which needs to modify tuple values. So I am passing a const..

Do not pass a const and you are going to be fine.

Comment: when i am not passing a const&, I get an error  error: a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "const thrust::device_reference<int>

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed `thrust`, I am not sure @PRP, never used it. *Always use the relevant tag*!

Comment: I think this problem is independent of the library used

Comment: Hmm why do you say that @PRP? Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892801/nvidia-thrust-device-ptr-const-correctness // I am leaving my answer for the next person to know.